# How to set Button text on clicking an Button which is generated Dynamically and using Dialog box

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using button as an date picker.After selecting the date the date should be set on the button.I'm generating this buttons pro grammatically or dynamic.When ever i click the button it only changes the text of the last button created.Thanks in advance...

```
private void init() {
    edit = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    listButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    dynamic = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamic);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addLayout();
        }
    });

    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0;i<edit.size();i++)
            {
      String names = edit.get(i).getText().toString();
                String Min = listButtons.get(i).getText().toString();

        }
    });
    }


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // set date picker as current date
        Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();
        day = today.monthDay;
        month = today.month;
        year= today.year;
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year,
                month, day);
    }
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year,
            month, day);
}
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth + 1;
        day = selectedDay;
        btn_date.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
    }
};
private void addLayout() {


    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setId(j);
    editText.setText("Test "+(j+1)+"     ");
    ll.addView(dose);
    edit.add(dose);
    // Create Button
    btn_date = new Button(this);
    // Give button an ID
    btn_date.setId(j);
    btn_date.setHint("Select Date");

    // set the layoutParams on the button
    btn_date.setLayoutParams(params);

    final int index = j;
    // Set click listener for button
    btn_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Clicked Button Index :" + index+dose.getText().toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(dose.getText().toString());
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID+index);

        }
    });

    //Add button to LinearLayout
    ll.addView(btn_date);
    listButtons.add(btn_date);      
    //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
    dynamic.addView(ll);  
    j++;    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onClick has the argument `View v` which refers to the element (Button) clicked. Cast to Button to make setText method available

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((Button)v).setText("whatever");
    }
```

if you want to access it from inside your addLayout method, just pass it on as an argument

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addLayout(v);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but I hope you managed to find out by now. If you did, consider sharing your findings :-)

Answer (score 0):

save the view you have in onclick event and when dialog is dismissed i.e. in datePickerListener use that instead of btn_date; something like this

```
Button clickedBtnDate = null;
btn_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedBtnDate = (Button)v //instance of the button clicked is saved here in clickedBtnDate
            Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Clicked Button Index :" + index+dose.getText().toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(dose.getText().toString());
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID+index);

        }
    });
```

Now in datePickerListener do

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth + 1;
        day = selectedDay;
        //btn_date.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
        clickedBtnDate.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
    }
};
```